# brew uninstall python error: Refusing to uninstall

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I decided to install python3 using brew: `brew install python`

How do I undo this? I tried `brew uninstall python` and got this error:

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7
because it is required by libxml2 and libxmlsec1, which are currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
```

I tried unlinking it `brew unlink python` - which worked, but am still unable to uninstall. Is the `--ignore-dependencies` the correct way to do this?

Comment: @dspencer Please make this an answer, it worked! `brew uninstall libxmlsec1 && brew uninstall libxml2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove `python` using `brew`, you will need to first uninstall the dependencies indicated, i.e. execute:

```
brew uninstall libxmlsec1 && brew uninstall libxml2
```

After that, you should be able to uninstall `python` using `brew uninstall python` as you tried originally.

You could use the suggestion from the error message, `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python`, however the dependencies would remain installed but would not function, which may cause further problems down the line.